# How to prevent iPhone from decoding URI component when trying to send a text in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, url, encodeuricomponent

I am trying to send a url in a text via iPhone and the url has user name as a query parameter. The user name can have space in it say, "Ben George". When I try to send a text via tapping an `<a>` tag my href is something like :

```
href = "sms:&body="+ encodeURIComponent(string)
```

which I get what I would like to ultimately show to the user in the body of text:

```
https://www.mylink.com?username=Ben%20George;
```

But it seems like the device decode the text and so the user name gets decoded and the link gets a space in the middle which wrecks the whole purpose of encoding. So I get:

```
https://www.mylink.com?username=Ben George
```

Any idea why this happens or how to prevent this?

Comment: What is "the device"?

Comment: What decodes it? How do you send it? etc.....

Comment: Hi, added more info, I'm trying on iphone to send a text when an <a> tag is tapped. Sending Email seems to be fine.

Comment: Why is node.js tag at Question?

Comment: oops, my bad, removed it !

Comment: This is only what you see as the end-user right? When you log the value, it's still the encoded one? That's just because browsers are smart-enough to know that humans aren't really good at percent-decoding from sight. Most browsers now do the same when your paste an percent-encoded URI in the address bar, or even in the anchor's preview. And they even do the conversion themselves if you happen to not type it correctly in the address bar.

Comment: @Kaiido It happens when the user taps the tag which goes to send the text. The URL that shows up in the text is decoded one with space and not %. So I don't understand how one is supposed to get something encoded if the device decode it ?

Comment: @guest271314 actually why not? why not having node.js tag? as far as I know one who knows node.js should know js. no?

Comment: Do you use node.js within the application? Still not certain what issue with code at Question.

Comment: @guest271314 On the back end ... Issue is that I try to encode a url but when user taps the tag to send the text which includes the encoded url, it shows the url as decoded meaning that space is space and not encoded as %

Comment: If you are using node.js you can adjust the code to render expected result, yes? _"one who knows node.js should know js. no?"_ What to you mean by "it shows the url"? What is "it"? What is expected result?

Comment: @guest271314. I'm not sure what's confusing, as stated above, I am trying to send a text via an <a> tag. Meaning when user taps the link, send a text. Now that text has a message which I am defining in href of <a>

Comment: Yes, you have described the apparent output.  What occurs when the current link is visited? What is the expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 , the expected result is to show the encoded url in the body of the text meaning something like: https://www.mylink.com?username=Ben%20George, notice the %20 instead of a space

Comment: Show the encoded URL where?

Comment: @guest271314 in the body of text.

Comment: Given that you are using node.js, you are in control of server,  yes? Why is space character within URL necessary?

Comment: @guest271314 space is part of username and I use node.js on the back-end side of stuff which is not directly related here. Problem is simple, I send an encoded string, and it shows up decoded in text which means my device (iphone) decode it.

Comment: @TheeBen Have no experience using iphone. Have you filed a bug report with the developer of the software which renders the output at the device?

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks for the comments but I'm pretty sure it's not a bug as this has been around for ages. I think it's about how I'm doing it. Thanks

Comment: So to make it clear, you are trying to fix something that is not broken. Stop. This is an UI feature of the browser. Let them handle it. If it is a broken feature, then open an issue.

Comment: @Kaiido well I'm not sure if it is an issue or if it's me doing something wrong If I knew it's an issue for sure I would open a bug report. Cheers

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the message to literally contain:

```
http://www.example.com/?username=Ben%20George
```

Then you need to URL-encode *that entire string* when including it in a `sms:` URL:

```
sms:&body=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%3Fusername%3DBen%2520George
```

Comment: I tried that but it seems to be decoding everything. You mean decoding it using encodeURIComponent() right? or do you mean I should decode mannually which wouldn't be possible since user name can change

Comment: I just want the url to be one string so when user taps on it, it directs the user to the url and not to a part of it. That's the whole reason